# Rebinding hoverIntent jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, ajax, hoverintent

I am using a combination of Drupal Views, ajax and the hoverIntent plug-in to display content. Problem is, after an ajax request the 'hoverIntent' event is no longer bound to the my selector (in this case each row of the view). Does anyone have a solution to this?

[Link to plug-in uncompressed hoverIntent js](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js)

[hoverIntent home page](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

My code below--

hoverIntent: This expands a row if you're cursor is over it and at the same time collapses all other rows.

```
$('.view-latest-new .views-field-field-story-lead-image-fid').addClass('expand');
var config = {
    over: function() {
         var expand = $(this).find(".expand");
         if(expand.css("display") == "none")
         {
            $(".expand").slideUp("fast");
            $(this).find(".expand").slideDown("fast");
         }
    }, 
    out: function() {
    }
};
$('.view-home .views-row').hoverIntent(config);
```

**EDIT:** Ajax:

```
    var container = $('#content-inner');

    $('#block-menu-secondary-links a').bind('click', function(){
        var trigger = $(this);
        var arg = trigger.attr('title');

        doAjax(arg,container);
        return false;
    });

    function doAjax(arg,container){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/ajax?view_name=home&view_display_id=page_1&view_args'+arg,
            timeout:5000,
            success: function(data){
                var result = Drupal.parseJson(data);
                updateContainer(result.display);
            },
        });
    };

    function updateContainer(content){
        container.html(content);
        $('.view-latest-new .views-field-field-story-lead-image-fid').addClass('expand');
        $('.view-latest-new .views-row').hoverIntent(config);
    }
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** I've found a solution; by adding `$('.view-home .views-row').hoverIntent(config);` into the updateContainer function. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it though. But it works.

Comment: let's see the ajax call.

Comment: Ajax code added. I also added a possible solution that I just found (edit 2).

Comment: yup, that's exactly what you need to do!  i wanted to make sure there wasn't any weirdness going on in your ajax first. 

i'd recomend moving that setup into a helper function and calling it in your document ready, and updateContainer function, so that you keep it in one place.

Comment: perfect thanks. hopefully it's useful for others

Comment: you should write that as an answer, and mark it as the answer, so this question will no longer show up as unanswered :)

Comment: thanks, it told me i had to wait a few hours. doing it now - but now it needs me to wait 20 hrs to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I have moved the 'hoverIntent' event into it's own function. Which then I have called when the document is ready and also after the ajax request has completed.

```
    function hoverInit() {
        $('.view-latest-new .views-field-field-story-lead-image-fid').addClass('expand').parent().hoverIntent(config);
    }

    hoverInit();

    function updateContainer(content){
        container.html(content);
        hoverInit();
    }
```